# MacOS: How/where do I store a programmatically created file within my app folder?

Tags: swift, macos, installation, macos-catalina

Very new to MacOS development (as in, completely new). I've developed a MacOS app (SwiftUI / Swift) and now figuring out a very things related to deployment.

My app generates a text file, but I'd like to save it within the app's folder (or whatever it is called) - and **not** in a user specified folder, and read it when I want. I can read resources from the `Assets.xcassets`  but I'd like to be able to save as well without making the user choose a location.

Is there a way I can write/read from the app folder (I'm struggling to explain as I'm very unfamiliar with this system)?

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't try storing content into the app bundle at runtime, instead, you should be using the appropriate "support" location provided by the OS, for example `FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)`

Comment: You can have a look at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer Note that you should NOT save files straight to this folder. You should create a sub folder and store the files inside. **All content in this directory should be placed in a custom subdirectory whose name is that of your app’s bundle identifier or your company** https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, I was using it as a starting point - but thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create a directory inside your application support folder, name it with app’s bundle identifier or your company and store all files that are not accessible to the user there:

> Use this directory to store all app data files except those associated
>   with the user’s documents. For example, you might use this directory
>   to store app-created data files, configuration files, templates, or
>   other fixed or modifiable resources that are managed by the app. **An
>   app might use this directory to store a modifiable copy of resources
>   contained initially in the app’s bundle**. A game might use this
>   directory to store new levels purchased by the user and downloaded
>   from a server. All content in this directory should be placed in a
>   custom subdirectory whose name is that of your app’s bundle identifier
>   or your company.

You should take some time and read the File System Basics [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1)

```
do {
    let applicationSupport = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "company name"
    let appSupportSubDirectory = applicationSupport.appendingPathComponent(bundleID,isDirectory: true)
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: appSupportSubDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    print(appSupportSubDirectory.path) // /Users/.../Library/Application Support/YourBundleIdentifier
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been a bit lost trying to piece it all, but these pointers go a long way in understanding. I did find some of the documentation, but when it said `archive` I thought it's some outdated old stuff not relevant. I will try this tomorrow and come back to mark the answer.

Comment: can this directory be created up front in my project folder on Xcode so that it's already there when the user installs the .dmg? Or do I need to programmatically create it at first launch? I'd like to be already there with some files to start with.

Comment: No. You can check if it exists and if it doesn’t create and copy your files there.